# VueJs. Управление заголовком и meta-данными страницы

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, vue-router, vue-cli

**Добрый день.**

Какие существуют способы (кроме как рендеринга на сервере) менять `title` и `meta-данные` страницы в зависимости от роутера? Пытался работать с `vue-meta`, но данный пакет подходит лишь для `Vue >2.6`, что мне не подходит. Если с `title` всё понятно и его можно менять на лету с помощью JS, то как быть с meta тегами, какие существуют способы их изменения?

Так же интересны способы реализации логики генерации `meta-данных`, планирую отдавать эти данные по запросу через API, нормальна ли такая практика?

В проекте используется **Vue 3** + **TS**.

Заранее спасибо за помощь и советы.

Comment: Мета-данные будут использоваться для SEO? Если да, нужен серверный рендеринг SSR. Vue router используется? Тогда посмотрите [эту статью](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-router-modify-head), там все объяснено, а вся соль в `router.beforeEach`. Я использую ровно такой способ.

Comment: @TotalPusher и что - работает SEO при таком использовании Vue-routera? По идее, ведь не должен

Comment: @Дмытрык, если SSR - то почему нет?

Comment: @TotalPusher SSR - 100% работает. Я, почему-то, подумал, что будет работать и без SSR, использую Vue router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долгое время искал и даже пытался адаптировать VueMeta под Vue 3, но безуспешно.
В итоге взглянул на фреймворк, который основан на `Vue 3` и `VueCLI` (`Quasar Framework`), в его комплекте есть плагин `Quasar Meta`, который позволяет работать с meta-tags и всем, что находится в теге `<head>...</heade>` и за пределами `div#app`. Единственное, что невозможно использовать `Quasar Meta` без самого `Quasar Framework`, от чего не слишком целесообразно подключать целый фреймворк, который основан на `Vue 3` лишь ради работы с мета тегами. Но пока это единственный вариант.